# How do I migrate model changes in pylons/sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, pylons

I created a simple model and then mapped it to a class using sqlalchemy in pylons:

```
tag_table = schema.Table('tag', meta.metadata,
    schema.Column('id', types.Integer,
                  schema.Sequence('tag_seq_id', optional=True),
                  primary_key=True),
    schema.Column('name', types.Unicode(20), nullable=False, unique=True),
)

class Tag(object):
    pass
orm.mapper(Tag, tag_table)
```

When I run paster setup-app development.ini I can see that the table is created but if I add another column to my table, how do I migrate the only column that I've added?

I've seen this migration in Rails and Django but is there something similar for Pylons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this tool: [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/)

Comment: sqlalchemy-migrate doesn't work if you are using PostgreSQL and non-default schemas.